# Android Intent filter for https scheme not working

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I know this question may appear duplicated with some other similar questions. I've reviewed all of them and still can't fix this issue.

I want to launch my android app when clicking a link on a webpage. It works as desired when I use a custom Scheme:

```
<!-- In the deployed webpage: -->
<a href="test://test.com">Launch application </a>

<!-- The Intent filter: -->
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="test" android:host="test.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

But when changing the scheme to "https":

```
<!-- In the deployed webpage: -->
<a href="https://test.com">Launch application </a>

<!-- The Intent filter: -->
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="test.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

the browser attempts to open the (nonexistent) page and ignores the intent filter.
It does not work for http, https, ftp, etc.

I'm running the app on Android 6.0, compiling: Minimum 11, target 23.

It seems like some mechanism is not allowing me to use the "reserved" schemes to launch an app, but I've not seen anything related to this in the posts.

Do you have any clue on what could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with Android Marshmallow there's a new `android:autoVerify` flag you can use to request Android to verify that a certain domain belongs to you and that you want links to open in your app and not the browser.

> "Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an app to designate
>   itself as the default handler of a given type of link"

See: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#intent-handler

Comment: Ok, I think this is the root of the problem. I will accept the answer as soon as I get this working. Do you know if the app link verification works with self-signed ssl certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the two `data` tags like so and removing the first `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` category as its not needed on the first intent-filter at all,  but necessary on the 2nd so that ["the activity should be an option for the default action to perform on a piece of data"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="test.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: can you edit your question and put the full xml for the activity in question (the full contents of the intent-filter tag's parent tag) from your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I've edited the question as requested. But remember, this actually works with any custom schema. It fails only when using "http" or "https".